keras.models.load_model() reinitalized custom lossfunction to default arguments
I am tring to make and then save a model in python file, and then train the model in another file.
This model uses a custom loss function that is in a seperate python file, so it can be imported into the 2 different python files.
I create and save the model as follows,
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=PoseLoss(Lambda=1, alpha=0, beta=0, gamma=0))
model.save("saved_model.keras")

Then the model is loaded as follows in the other python file
from Loss_function import PoseLoss
# from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import keras

model = keras.models.load_model("saved_model.keras", custom_objects={'PoseLoss': PoseLoss(Lambda=1, alpha=0, beta=0, gamma=0)},safe_mode=False)

And here is the cutsom loss function (loss function to calculate the error between groundthruth extrnisc and extrinsic camera parameters, feel free to give me tips on that if you see something that could be improved)
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class PoseLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, Lambda=1, alpha=1, beta=1, gamma=1, name="PoseLoss", reduction='auto'):
        super(PoseLoss, self).__init__(name=name, reduction=reduction)
        self.Lambda = Lambda
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.gamma = gamma

        # Print the initialization values
        print(f"Initialized PoseLoss with Lambda={self.Lambda}, alpha={self.alpha}, beta={self.beta}, gamma={self.gamma}")

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # Split the true and predicted values into position, rotation, and camera parameters
        True_pos = y_true[:,:3]
        True_rot = y_true[:,3:7]
        True_Intrincs = y_true[:,7:10]
        True_Distortion = y_true[:,10]

        Pred_pos = y_pred[:,:3]
        Pred_rot = y_pred[:,3:7]
        Pred_Intrincs = y_pred[:,7:10]
        Pred_Distortion = y_pred[:,10]

        # Calculate the position loss
        Position_Loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(True_pos - Pred_pos))

        # Calculate the rotation loss
        Rotation_Loss = self.quaternion_distance(Pred_rot, True_rot)
        
        # Calculate the intrinsic parameters loss
        Focal_Length_Loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(True_Intrincs[:,0] - Pred_Intrincs[:,0]))
        Principal_Point_Loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(True_Intrincs[:,1:3] - Pred_Intrincs[:,1:3]))
        
        # Calculate the distortion parameter loss
        Distortion_Loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(True_Distortion - Pred_Distortion))

        # Combine all the losses with weighting factors
        Loss = (Position_Loss + 
                self.Lambda * Rotation_Loss + 
                self.alpha * Focal_Length_Loss + 
                self.beta * Principal_Point_Loss + 
                self.gamma * Distortion_Loss)

        return Loss

    def quaternion_distance(self, q, r):
        """
        Batch quaternion distances, used as loss
        Args:
            q (tf.Tensor): shape=[Nx4]
            r (tf.Tensor): shape=[Nx4]

        Returns:
            tf.Tensor: shape=[N]
        """
        t = self.quatmultiply(q, self.quatinv(r))
        norm_t = tf.norm(t[:, 1:], axis=1)
        abs_t0 = tf.abs(t[:, 0])
        return 2 * tf.atan2(norm_t, abs_t0)
    
    def quatmultiply(self, q, r):
        """
        Batch quaternion multiplication
        Args:
            q (tf.Tensor): shape=[Nx4]
            r (tf.Tensor): shape=[Nx4]

        Returns:
            tf.Tensor: shape=[Nx4]
        """
        t = tf.stack([
            r[:, 0] * q[:, 0] - r[:, 1] * q[:, 1] - r[:, 2] * q[:, 2] - r[:, 3] * q[:, 3],
            r[:, 0] * q[:, 1] + r[:, 1] * q[:, 0] - r[:, 2] * q[:, 3] + r[:, 3] * q[:, 2],
            r[:, 0] * q[:, 2] + r[:, 1] * q[:, 3] + r[:, 2] * q[:, 0] - r[:, 3] * q[:, 1],
            r[:, 0] * q[:, 3] - r[:, 1] * q[:, 2] + r[:, 2] * q[:, 1] + r[:, 3] * q[:, 0]
        ], axis=1)
        
        return t

    def quatinv(self, q):
        """
        Batch quaternion inversion
        Args:
            q (tf.Tensor): shape=[Nx4]

        Returns:
            tf.Tensor: shape=[Nx4]
        """
        t = tf.identity(q)
        t = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(-t[:, 0], axis=1), t[:, 1:]], axis=1)
        return t

In the loss function I added a print statment to print the arguments when it is initalized, here is the cell output of the load model command in the 2nd code block. In the cell output can be seen that the loss function is initialized twice, first with the correct values (most likely from the custom_objects={'PoseLoss': PoseLoss(Lambda=1, alpha=0, beta=0, gamma=0)} part in the load model line). Then the model is reininitalized with the default values.
Initialized PoseLoss with Lambda=1, alpha=0, beta=0, gamma=0
Initialized PoseLoss with Lambda=1, alpha=1, beta=1, gamma=1
WARNING:absl:Skipping variable loading for optimizer 'Adam', because it has 873 variables whereas the saved optimizer has 1 variables. 


Tried to change set the default values to nothing but this did not work and gave an error that i did not give enough arguments.
